# How to remove a transaction line from a deposit in QBXML?

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbwc

When modifying invoices and bills I can work with line items just fine. To add items I set the `TxnLineID` to `-1` and to remove the item you simply do not include it in the mod request. So instead of storing the `TxnLineID` for later mods I set them all to `-1` in mods, this effectively removes all the current items and adds all the items I want back in. This method does not seem to hold true for deposits. If I successfully create a deposit with a transaction line then run a mod request with zero lines. The deposit still has one transaction associated with it.

This request was processed successfully, but the response still included the original `DepositLine`.

```
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <DepositModRq>
            <DepositMod>
                <TxnID>a68sdf4as-864564848</TxnID>
                <EditSequence>1388524567</EditSequence>
                <DepositToAccountRef>
                    <ListID>a65sd4fasd-468468465</ListID>
                </DepositToAccountRef>
            </DepositMod>
        </DepositModRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Looking at the [OCR](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html), it looks like I have to delete the deposit and create a new one. Are there any better options out there?

Comment: Trying to understand - why are you trying to run a mod request that would make the Deposit have 0 transactions associated with it? Isn't that essentially the same as deleting it?

Comment: @BenStrombeck I simplified this question as much as I could. In a real scenario there would be multiple transactions and the mod request would also have multiple transactions, but more or less than the add request.

Comment: alright. Well sorry I can't give you much of an answer. The main thing that comes to mind for me is that QB doesn't like you editing transactions that affect the bank account after they've been cleared. Have you tried this on a deposit that hasn't yet been cleared?